# Wrong datepicker behavior

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to show a flat jQuery datepicker with three months and initially the current month in the middle. My code :

```
$('#threeMonths').datepicker({

    numberOfMonths:[1,3],
    showCurrentAtPos: 1
});
```

In this form it changes the months displayed whenever I click on any date, and always one month back, why is that and how could I fix it?

Update >

The solution that fits my needs is to increment drawMonth in the onSelect callback, as my editing of Berker's answer demonstrates.

Comment: why are you using id to implement datepicker? use classes for datepicker such as `$(".date").datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [1, 3], showCurrentAtPos: 3 });` so you can implement this datepicker every "date" class input.

Comment: @ Berker I'm rusty on my html, could you please elaborate with an example on how that would work?

Comment: i also added some html in my answer.

Comment: if you were to read more closely my post you will see your answer does not solve the issue.

Comment: sorry about it i updated my answer.. it solves the issue now.

Comment: it would be desired for both of the adjacent months to work the same as for the main month

Comment: wait you wanna make it just show 3 spesific month that will never change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        // Add date picker
        $(".date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            showCurrentAtPos: 1,
            showWeeks: true,
            showStatus: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            highlightWeek: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,

            // hot fix (month back slide problem)
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { 
                inst.drawMonth +=1; 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
    <div class="date">Select a date!</div>
```

Comment: As I wrote before, html... not a forte for me at the moment what would the html tag look like for your given script?

Comment: its `$(".date")` and each input on your form that has date class `<input... class="date" ../>` will get the datepicker..

Comment: OK thank you very much for this, I see what you did there but what I want is a flat datepicker... as in : as soon as the page loads the three months are visible, I do not want a pop-up datepicker... I apologize if my demand was ambiguous.

Comment: if you can view your page in a browser and click on any date you will notice that the months keep moving back, and I don't want that, it's probably a datepicker bug or something...

Comment: @PhantasmePunk yes this was a bug but I fixed the issue with the code above, try now.

Comment: i appreciate the effort hugely, however,the fix is only for the current month, it would be desirable for the other two displayed months also

Comment: you know this issue got me very interested. i like solving unexpected problems and im glad to see that you accomplished it.